# Proving that $f(x) = (a_1 a_2 \dots a_n)^x - a_1^x - a_2^x - \dots - a_n^x$ is increasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer and let there be $n$ real numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n \geq 1.$ Define $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x) = (a_1 a_2 \dots a_n)^x - a_1^x - a_2^x - \dots - a_n^x.$$ Prove that $f$ is increasing.

---

I want to show that $f' \geq 0$ over $[0, \infty)$ since it will soon follow that $f$ is increasing. However, I am unsure of how to calculate the derivative of $f(x).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that since $a_i\geq 1$, $a_1\cdot a_2\cdot...a_n\geq a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. This means that, since exponentiation is an increasing function for base $\geq 1$, we have: $$(a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot...a_n)^x\geq a_1^x, a_2^x,...,a_n^x$$
Also, $$\frac {d(a^x)}{dx}=a^x \ln a$$
From properties of logarithm, $\ln(a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ...a_n)=\ln(a_1)+\ln(a_2)+...+\ln(a_n)$. This is enough to prove the statement. Take a derivative, and you'll notice that it can be represented in a way that each term is positive. Can you continue?

**Edit:** Since you asked for more help, here goes:
We have, from using the previous paragraph:
$$f'(x)=(a_1\cdot a_2\cdot...a_n)^x (\ln a_1+\ln a_2+...+\ln a_n)-a_1^x \ln a_1-a_2^x \ln a_2-...-a_n^x \ln a_n$$
Now combine terms with same coefficients (same $\ln$ term). Can you see that each particular term will be positive?

Comment: Isn't the derivative of $\ln(x)$ $\frac{1}{x}$? So it suffices to show that $\frac{1}{a_1 \cdot \dots \cdot a_n} = \frac{1}{a_1} + \dots + \frac{1}{a_n},$ right?

Comment: How exactly does this prove that $f$ is increasing though?

Comment: No, the derivative is not $\frac {\ln x}{x}$. Why do you think so?

Comment: @questionasker:  It is true that the derivative of $\ln x$ is $1/x$, but there's no $\ln x$ anywhere here to begin with. The $x$ is always _outside_ the logarithms; only the $a_i$ (which are constants) are inside.

Comment: I'm a bit confused right now. First, from what I understand, we wish to show that $(a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot...a_n)^x\geq a_1^x, a_2^x,...,a_n^x,$ and afterwards we take the derivative of this?

Comment: Alright wait, I'll provide some more of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way: decompose $f(x) = (a_1a_2 ...)^xg(x)$, and notice that each factor is increasing and positive.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^x-a_1^x-a_2^x-\cdots-a_n^x$

$\implies f(x)=(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^x-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^x$

$\implies f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^x-\frac{d}{dx}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^x)$

$\implies f'(x)=(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^x\ln(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{d}{dx}a_i^x$

$\implies f'(x)=(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^x\ln(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^x\ln(a_i)$

$\implies f'(0)=(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^0)\ln(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^0\ln(a_i)$

$\implies f'(0)=\ln(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(a_i)$

$\implies f'(0)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(a_i)$

$\implies f'(0)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i-ln(a_i))$

Which is obviously greater than $0$

$\therefore f'(0)>0$